# Could not understand the meaning of decision tree parameters

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have 3 labels (male, female, na), denoted as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import tree

labels = [0,1,2]
```

Each label was defined by 3 features (height, weight, and age) as the training data:

Training data for males:

```
male_height = np.array([111,121,137,143,157])
male_weight = np.array([60,70,88,99,75])
male_age = np.array([41,32,73,54,35])

males = np.vstack([male_height,male_weight,male_age]).T
```

Training data for females:

```
female_height = np.array([91,121,135,98,90])
female_weight = np.array([32,67,98,86,56])
female_age = np.array([51,35,33,67,61])

females = np.vstack([female_height,female_weight,female_age]).T
```

Training data for not availables:

```
na_height = np.array([96,127,145,99,91])
na_weight = np.array([42,97,78,76,86])
na_age = np.array([56,35,49,64,66])

nas = np.vstack([na_height,na_weight,na_age]).T
```

So, the complete training data are:

```
trainingData = np.vstack([males,females,nas])
```

Complete labels are:

```
labels =  np.repeat(labels,5)
```

I have to make decision tree rule, so I fitted as follows:

```
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(trainingData, labels)
```

The tree I produced is here:
[image]
However, I could not understand the meaning of this tree.
Could someone help me to learn the meaning of the followings as displayed in the image, and with regard to my example dataset:

```
samples, value, gini, X[0], X[1], X[2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each level of the tree, the algorithm has selected a particular feature to partition. This is chosen to give the optimal split of data according to class. So the first split, height has been selected, hence 'X[0] <= 105'.
'samples' shows the split of data, so 6 samples to the left (all those samples with height <= 105) and 9 samples to the right (all those samples with height > 105)
'value' I think shows the classification. It is always on the leaf nodes. For example, value = [0, 1, 0] indicates that sample would be classified as female
'gini' I'm not certain about without looking at the details of this particular decision tree implementation

Comment: Thanks Mark Purser for your nice explanation. My final goal is to make if else statement in Python. So I have asked new question, can you help me on my new question too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828265/converting-decision-tree-into-statement-in-python

Comment: I am curious what the optimal split means when you have three classes? For two classes, I would imagine selecting a variable and a threshold that maximizes Prob(class1) when var<T which automatically maximizes Prob(class2) when var>=T. You just need to try all your variables and a bunch of thresholds. But three class case confuses me...